# Datatables responsive not working when initialised with no data

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, datatables

I'm using the [Datatables responsive extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/) on a datatable with ajax sourced server-side data. Initialisation is like this:

```
 var oTable = $('#sales-report').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": $("#rooturl").val() + '/Reporting/Reports/PopulateDatatable',
            "data": function ( d ) {
                return $.extend( {}, d, {
                    "date_start_filter": $('#FilterDateStart').val(),
                    etc...
             });
        }
    },
    'columns': [
                {
                    'data': 1
                },
                 etc...
               ]
      });
```

The table looks like this, the `responsive` class is the initialiser:

```
<table class="table responsive table-bordered table-striped table-highlight nowrap " id="sales-report" width="100%" >
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>SKU</th>
          etc....
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

When the page loads, there is no data in the table.  The user then chooses filtering options and hits `search` which calls `draw()`.

Assuming data is returned from the search, the datatable works fine, but the responsive 'collapsing' feature is not enabled. If the page is then refreshed without changing anything else, then the collapsing works.

I've tried initialising the table differently but the results are still the same.  I'm sure this has something to do with the fact that the data is ajax sourced, but I'm now stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> **SOLUTION**

Try to put the following code after the `search()` to recalculate the widths used by responsive extension after a change in the display.

```
$('#sales-report').DataTable()
   .columns.adjust()
   .responsive.recalc();
```

See [`responsive.recalc()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29) API method for more information.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/Ltga3n4u/) for code and demonstration.

> **LINKS**

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solution to the most common problems with jQuery DataTables and Bootstrap Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I added `<div class="table-scrollable">` before the table.

```
<div class="table-scrollable">
    <table class="table responsive table-bordered table-striped table-highlight nowrap " id="sales-report" width="100%" >
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>SKU</th>
              etc....
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```